# Object has no attribute append

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with the discord module, but I have no experience with async functions.

Here's the part of the code that doesn't work:

```
@client.command()
async def bank(ctx):
    global bal
    if ctx.author.name in users:
        bal.append(0)
    else:
        print("nope")
    print(bal)
```

`bal` is previously set to an empty list outside of all functions.

It returns a huge error, but it mainly says :

```
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: `bal` must be of type `list` to `append`.

Comment: If you get that error, then `bal` is not a list. Double check to make sure you aren't accidentally overwriting the list somewhere.

Comment: Error seems to indicate that you have a command named `bal`, which is overwriting your `bal` list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the error `AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'append'`, it looks like the `bal` variable is of type `object` and not a list.

You can verify this by checking the type before the if statement like this:

```
print(type(bal))
```

Please make sure that the type is list for `append` to work.